# rewrite url to root directory with url cutting

Tags: .htaccess

I have such urls:

```
http://site.ru/ontent/wefwefw/article.php?article=369-tayskaya-kuhnya-recept-s-foto
http://site.ru/ontent/wefwefw/article.php?article=32237-ogurci-recepti-na-zimu
http://site.ru/ontent/wefwefw/article.php?article=90-ogurci-na-zimu-recepti-po-koreyski
```

I want to rewrite tham like:

```
http://site.ru/tayskaya-kuhnya-recept-s-foto.html
http://site.ru/ogurci-recepti-na-zimu.html
```

I tried smth like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ontent/wefwefw/$1 [L]
```

But how cut unnecessary parts of string?

Comment: You can't do it directly with *mod_rewrite* since you have some `ID` variable parameter linked to each article in your urls

Answer (score 0):

Unless article.php is able to derive the right article from the title alone, what you want to do is not possible. mod_rewrite is good at rewriting things, but it can't summon an article-id from thin air if it isn't in the original request. You would have something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ ontent/wefwefw/article.php?article=$1 [L]
```

When you would request `http://site.ru/tayskaya-kuhnya-recept-s-foto.html`, it will load `http://site.ru/ontent/wefwefw/article.php?article=tayskaya-kuhnya-recept-s-foto`. Then you have to get the id 369 in some other way based on the title if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The best in this case is:

```
http://site.ru/369-tayskaya-kuhnya-recept-s-foto.html
```

redirect to

```
http://site.ru/ontent/wefwefw/article.php?article=369
```

with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\d+)-[^/]*\.html$ ontent/wefwefw/article.php?article=$1 [L]
```